# Makefile and rm -f file.{ext1,ext2,ext3} issue

Tags: bash, gnu-make

Could you explain me, why Makefile rule:

```
clean:
    rm -f foo.{bar1,bar2,bar3}
```

does not result in removing files: foo.bar1 foo.bar2 and foo.bar3?
I believe I saw pattern like that many times in various Makefiles, but I'm currently writing my own Makefile and can't make that rule work correctly (no files are removed).

I'm using:

- gnu make 3.81
- gnu bash 4.1.5

Bash evals that pattern as I suspect:

```
$ echo test.{a,b,c}
test.a test.b test.c
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Thank to David's hint I found solution for the problem described above.
The gnu make uses the /bin/sh by default and that is why a.{1,2,3} isn't evaluated to a.1 a.2 a.3.

To make 'make' use bash instead of sh add following line to your Makefile:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

from now a.{1,2,3} will be considered as a.1 a.2 a.3

Comment: @Ak91: You typically write self-answers *as* answers. Answering your own questions is allowed and encouraged. It will, however, be a couple of days before you can accept your own answer and there will be no points for that.

Comment: @dmckee: Sorry, I'm new to Stackoverflow site. I must learn its rules.

Comment: @AK91: I mentioned it not only by way of orientation, but because I'd be happy to vote for your correct self answer...

Comment: Me too. (Glad my hint helped)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a file named `clean` in the directory? If so, make will consider that target up to date and won't run the corresponding command. To fix that, add this line to your makefile:

```
.PHONY: clean
```

If when you run `make clean` you get the output

```
make: `clean' is up to date.
```

then that's probably your problem.

Comment: There is no file named 'clean' in directory. The rule is launched when I type: "make clean", but {} isn't evaled so rm tries to remove "foo.{bar1,bar2,bar3}" not the foo.bar ...

Answer (score -1):

It's because the shell isn't being invoked here, but rather rm is directly. Since the shell does the {} substitution, what rm 'sees' is the raw  foo.{bar1,bar2,bar3} string. As there's no such file, nothing happens.

You should use one of GNUmake's string macros to have it perform the expansion for you.

Comment: The makefile in the question worked for me without any macros (in make 3.80 and bash 3.00), so I have my doubts about this.

Comment: Oh, and according to the `make` documentation, commands are interpreted by `/bin/sh`.

Comment: I don't want to use macros, since I believe it's possible to eval that patterns without macros. See: http://google.com/codesearch?q=file:Makefile$+rm.*\{.*,  - unfortunately that does not work for me.

Comment: David, that's make sense now:
$ bash
$ echo a.{1,2,3}
a.1 a.2 a.3
$ sh
$ echo a.{1,2,3}
a.{1,2,3}

Any ideas, how to force make to use bash instead of sh?

Comment: Ok. I found the solution after David's hint about that make uses /bin/sh by default. If you want to use bash, just add on the top of Makefile line SHELL=/bin/bash
Now 'clean' rule works fine for me :)